# dois eventos onclick no mesmo loop

Tags: javascript

olá. Estou a dar os primeiros passos em javascript e tenho uma duvida para a qual ainda não encontrei uma resposta que realmente compreenda.

Estou a tentar interagir adicionar uma função de click e uma função de reset a 3 botões usando o mesmo loop mas só funciona se eu tiver um loop para cada função.  Eu não consigo perceber porque não posso usar o mesmo.

Obrigada

ex:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#game button");
var resetbtn =document.getElementById("reset");
var symbol = "X";
   
    
for(var i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++ )   { 

     buttons[i].onclick = function(){
     
      if(this.textContent == ""){
      
       this.textContent = symbol; 
       
       if(symbol=="X"){
        symbol= "0";
       
       }
       else{
        symbol = "X";
       }
       
      }

      
     }

     function reset(){
      //for(var j = 0; j<3; j++){   --> so quando eu altero a variavel abaixo para a do novo loop - J -  é que funciona

       buttons[i].textContent = "";
      }
     }
    
    
     resetbtn.onclick = function(){
      reset();
     } 
    }
```

```html
<div id="game">
   <button type="button"></button>
   <button type="button"></button>
   <button type="button"></button>
  </div>
  <div>
   <button id="reset" type="button">reset</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Você está tentando colocar 3 funções on-click no botão reset, ele só vai aceitar uma.

Answer (score 0):

Ao criar a função `reset()` dentro do laço, e mesma é sobrescrita resultando a variável `i` no último valor após o `for` ter finalizado, ou seja, `i` será igual a `3`, logo, `buttons[i]` (ou `buttons[3]`) resultará em erro porque não existe um botão de índice `3` (o máximo é `buttons[2]`).

Quando o loop é finalizado, o valor da variável de controle `i` será o próximo valor definido em `i++` de acordo com a condição `i < 3`, ou seja, o valor de `i` será `2+1=3`. Com isso a função `reset()` será `buttons[3].textContent = "";`. E como só existem 3 botões no `var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("#game button");`, o código lançará o erro:

> Cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined

Quando você usa um novo `for` dentro da função `reset()` (independente da variável ser `j`) você está criando uma nova rotina que irá funcionar normalmente.

Em suma, você não deve criar uma função única dentro de um laço, porque o rodar o laço uma irá sobrescrever a outra, e não vai conseguir reaproveitar a variável `i` nesse contexto. Tanto a função `reset()` quanto a `resetbtn.onclick` deveriam estar fora do laço `for`.

Comment: Sam, Obrigada pela resposta.  Então ao usar i a primeira vez ele já corre o loop todo até ao ultimo valor, o que significa que usar i uma segunda ou terceira vez noutras funções não faz sentido porque i já terminou. Correcto?  Espero ter percebido .  Mais uma vez, obrigada

Comment: Sim, a função está sendo recriada a cada loop, e o último valo do `i` será 3.